# Firebase angular $authWithOAuthRedirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth, firebase, angularfire

I'm using Firebase and Angular and Angular fire to to OAuth login.

Everything works fine when I use `$authWithOAuthPopup`, but that transport is not always available so when I have to fallback to `$authWithOAuthRedirect` I can't get it to work.

With this code, the following happens:

1. Execute the login("twitter") function
2. See "CHECK 1" in the console.
3. User redirects to twitter OAuth flow (url looks something like: `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=<longtoken>`
4. User redirects back to my angular application (url looks like: `http://localhost:3101/##?&__firebase_request_key=<longrequestkey>`

The promise callbacks: `CHECK 2`, `CHECK 3`, `CHECK 4` never get run and the $onAuth function (`CHECK 5`) never gets run.

If I use $authWithOAuthPopup, it works as expected (as long as that transport is supported).

---

```
authObj = $firebaseAuth new Firebase(<firebase root>);
authObj.$onAuth(function(authData){
  console.log("CHECK 5");
});


$scope.login = function(provider) {
  console.log("CHECK 1");
  authObj.$authWithOAuthRedirect(provider).then(function(authData) {
    console.log("CHECK 2");
  }).then(function() {
    console.log("CHECK 3");
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log("CHECK 4");
  });
}
```

I tried to reproduce this with another example: https://dylan.firebaseapp.com/. In this reproduced example everything works fine. It's something else in my application that is causing some funny business.

Libraries:

- https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js
- https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.3/angularfire.min.js
- https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.3.1/firebase.js

Comment: What version of AngularFire are you using?

Comment: @DavidEast 1.1.3. I also updated the question with angular, angularfire and firebase versions

Comment: Can you create a plunkr or JSBin? Also do you get an error in the catch?

Comment: No error in the catch. I never see "CHECK 2", "CHECK 3" or "CHECK 4"

Comment: I'll try to repro this in a plunkr

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem in an app of mine. After redirecting, I get back to my angular app with the URL showing the `__firebase_request_key` param and nothing happens. Any ideas?